# Move workstations from one OU to another

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012, automation

I have pieced together the below powershell script but when i run it on my DC i get the below error message.

My overall goal is to have the script pick up on any workstations within the Computers OU and move them into the Workstations OU which is a child OU within the London OU parent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Powershell script

```
$computerstomove = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=TCWSTEST)" -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=temporis,DC=corp"
foreach ($computertomove in $computerstomove) {
    Move-ADObject $computertomove -TargetPath "OU=London,OU=Workstations,DC=temporis,DC=corp"
}
```

Error msg:

```
Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted
At \\tcws40\c$\Scripts\Workstation move.ps1:4 char:2
+     Move-ADObject $computertomove -TargetPath "OU=London,OU=Workstations,DC=tempori ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=TCWSTEST,CN=...emporis,DC=corp:ADComputer) [Move-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8329,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

Comment: Could be a spelling error.
Could you provide us with the output of "Get-ADComputer" and [adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=London,OU=Workstations,DC=temporis,DC=corp")

Answer (score 1):

First, no need for the unnecessary `foreach`. This should work just fine:

```
Get-ADComputer TCWSTEST | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=London,OU=Workstations,DC=temporis,DC=corp"
```

Second, I tested both ways (yours and mine) in my environment, and they both worked without error. Have you confirmed that if the "object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted" is true? Double-check your DN of `"OU=London,OU=Workstations,DC=temporis,DC=corp"` because you will receive this error message if you have a typo in your DN.

Answer (score 0):

What i did in the end to make my life a whole lot easier was change the default folder as to where PCs are placed when added to the domain. i used the redircmp command  on my DC within Powershell and it worked a treat.

redircmp "OU=Workstations,OU=London,DC=temporis,DC=corp"

Comment: Like I said, you have a type. In this answer, you have Workstations first in your DN. In your question, you have London first.